# What does "smallest" mean in this definition?

Tags: definition, first-order-logic

> In first-order logic, a set $\tau$ of terms is the **smallest set** of strings (finite sequences of symbols) over the sets of variables, constants, and function symbols such that:
>
> - Any variable is a term.
> - Any constant is a term.
> - if $f^n$ is a function symbol of arity $n$, and $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ are terms then $f^nt_1t_2...t_n$ is also a term.

What does *the smallest set* mean here? Is it really possible for more than one set satisfying the above properties to exist? If yes, an example would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps it just means that $\tau$ doesn't include anything superfluous, such as strings that are not terms or infinite strings.

Comment: Oh I see, that makes sense. Are these kind of definitions common in math?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Kevin P. Barry comments, this is exactly to rule out unwanted objects. For example, consider the following definition of the set $E$ of even integers:

> $E$ is the smallest set containing $0$ and closed under the maps $x\mapsto x+2$ and $x\mapsto x-2$.

The "smallest set" condition there is crucial: if we omit it, there are lots of sets satisfying the definition (e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ itself, $E\cup\{\pi+2k: k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$, and so forth). Another famous example of a definition of this form is one of the standard definitions of the natural numbers in set theory:

> The set of finite ordinals is the smallest set containing $\emptyset$ and closed under the map $x\mapsto x\cup\{x\}$.

These show up all over the place in mathematics. *(A useful term here is "inductive definition" or "recursive definition.")* Generally we have the following useful heuristic:

> Most of the time, "the smallest set $X$ such that [stuff]" is exactly the intersection of all the sets such that [stuff].

In fact, this is usually how we prove that a smallest such set *exists* - that's something we can't ignore! (E.g. "The smallest infinite set of natural numbers" isn't a thing.)

---

Incidentally, I've said a bit more about this in the specific context of formal languages (as in your OP) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3035858/28111).